# How do I properly implement border-image using css?

Tags: html, css

With respect to the following code, without the image, solid green border is OK, but with the image specs, all I see are the images in the 4 corners.

My code:

```css
.content {
    padding: 1em;
        
    border:       solid darkgreen;
    border-width: 20px 20px;   /* v, h */
    
    border-image:        url("White_House_pics/garland.gif");
    webkit-border-image: url("White_House_pics/garland.gif");
    border-image-repeat: repeat;    
}
```

Again, without the image, solid green border is OK, but with the image specs, all I see are the images in the 4 corners.

?????

I really have looked around, but something obvious is escaping me.

Comment: Can't you create a snippet that reproduces your problem? You have enough reputation to know how to ask a good question...

Comment: I did ask a good question “If I have A, no problem ... if B, this problem surfaces”. Short and simple. Over my many years, I have found constructing Fiddles to sometimes consume more time than constructing short and simple to begin with.  Catch you later ... am enroute to Arlington National Cemetery where I deal with a lot of sadness from folk whose children threw themselves on hand grenades and such to protect others

Comment: OH MY: shades of my golf game = border-image-slice SOLVED!

Comment: THANK GOD for this beauty: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Border-image_generator